# Как пишутся марки сыра?

Tags: орфография

И у меня вопрос про сыр))) Вчера писала текст о сортах сыра, но вот не совсем разобралась, как их оформлять в плане кавычек и прописных букв? Например: рокфор, пармезан, дор блю  и костромской.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эти названия сами по себе стали именами нарицательными, здесь кавычки и заглавные не требуются. Но они могут потребоваться если идут в списке названий, где есть и собственно ***марки*** сыров.   
*На прилавках обнаружены сыры: "Ольтермани", "Колбасный", "Волна".*

Однако и в таком специализированном тесте кавычки могут опускаться, если их число портит восприятие текста, Вот как здесь:  
http://www.cheesemania.ru/tverdye.shtml
Заглавная при этом сохраняется.

Так что тут могут быть варианты - в зависимости от контекста и направленности статьи.

Answer (score 1):

На Грамоте.ру написано, что при употреблении в качестве торговой марки названия продовольственных товаров пишутся с прописной буквы в кавычках. Например, сыр «Моцарелла».  Названия продуктов в бытовом употреблении пишутся со строчной буквы без кавычек: голландский сыр.

Comment: Там неточность. Не в бытовом употреблении, а именно - в качестве нарицательных названий сортов, не марок.